# Windows Phone 8 more Items in row as template

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, itemtemplate

I'm new in Windows Phone 8 development and I want to create a page with any number of items sorted in two columns as this great image shows.

[image: template]

I was trying to use **LongListSelector**, but i was able to create only one column. So what control should I use to create such a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install windows phone toolkit

add this code in your xaml in phone:PhoneApplicationPage

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

this is your list code

```
<ListBox x:Name="pictureListBox" Margin="10,101,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="pictureListBox_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Image x:Name="Image" Source="{Binding Thumb}" Stretch="Uniform" Width="200" Height="200" Margin="10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: This isn't solve a problem. It shows images horizontally. I used <phone:PanoramaItem Header="featured" Orientation="Horizontal" Foreground="Black">, If I changed Orientation to Vertical then it shows Vertically and not in Multiple rows, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Toolkit for Windows Phone and look at the WrapPanel, this will solve your problem :-)